# How to nominate something as not a duplicate when flagged as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I came across a question that is not a duplicate, however it's been marked incorrectly as a duplicate.

The question is [how to extract a substring in bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16484972/how-to-extract-a-substring-in-bash)

There are specific differences. The linked item is about substrings based on delimeters, while the original question is purely substrings. This has resulted in very different answers and the accepted answer for the alleged duplicate question is valuable.

So how does one question the fact that it has been flagged as duplicate? I cannot comment on the question as the vote has completed. However it is apparent to someone familar with the technical nature of the questions that they are in fact different.

**Clarification:** It’s possible that the question is a duplicate of a different question, just not the question that has been stated it is the duplicate of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your profile reputation here, you might be able to see a `reopen` link as in the attached screenshot.  If you believe it is not a dupe & have a strong opinion on that, just `flag` the question with specific details. A moderator will review & can most likely vote to `reopen` it!

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I wasn't sure about flagging it, but have now done so :-)

Comment: I followed these instructions and my flag was declined.  I was given this response: Moderator flags must not be used to resolve wrong dupe closures. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291977. @ping the gold badge user who closed the question in the comments and inform them the same.  
I had already upvoted the answer and when I tried to undo, was disallowed.

Answer (score 2):

@ping the gold badge user who closed the question in the comments and inform them the reason the question is not a duplicate.  Flags involve Moderators who may not have the subject matter expertise to determine if the duplicate marking is appropriate or not.

Comment: In my case, the gold badge user refused to reopen the question.  Not because it was a duplicate, but because the answer was not, in his opinion, idiomatic of best design principals.  So, only thing I could do was warn others away from incorrect answer flagged as correct answer in a comment.