# Should moderator flags be used to handle incorrect question closure

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons

( Take this as a hypothetical situation )

A question was closed by a gold tag user and a single normal user. There was no consensus on the closure as normally five users should vote.

The questions was closed incorrectly. Gold user didn't respond. I flagged the question. The flag was handled with a response: *declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention*

That response seems strange.

So in a hypothetical situation, flagging a question that was incorrectly closed by a gold user, is in my opinion the correct way to handle the situation, since it could be reopened immediately to correct the error. I don't think ignoring it or leaving it to be handled in the reopen queue should be used in this situation.

Comment: Is this or isn't this hypothetical? This is something that's going to inherently involve evaluation of how "wrongly handled" the situation actually was, so it's going to be hard to conclusively answer a general hypothetical case.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Actually, users who applied a binding close vote can be pinged (i.e., dupehammerers and mods).

Answer (score 18):

No, moderator flags should be used for things the community cannot handle on its own without moderator intervention. There's a reopen queue for exactly this situation. Moderators don't need to get involved.

Comment: How do I suggest a question should be reopened? The flow of the queues are not always clear for users who don't have access to all of them. For instance, I thought the only way to resolve an incorrect duplicate question was to flag it. There's no "this duplicate is wrong" link.

Comment: @giusti If it's your own question, you should edit it to explain why it's not a duplicate. If it's someone else's, then you should be able to flag it if you can make a strong case.

Comment: @BilltheLizard What about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193987/how-to-auto-increment-ios-notification-badge-with-firebase-cloud-messaging). It closed but it should not have closed. This is a different question. Should we wait for those gold badge users who voted it for close to reopen it? Even I'm unable to ping them in comments. So can we inform them or get their attention to this question? There should be any option or help for such things.

Comment: @BilltheLizard As per your comment I flagged this question to moderator with a reason but my flag was declined.

Answer (score 14):

If a gold badge holder (who presumably know a lot about the topic) decided to close the question as a duplicate, why do you think a moderator (who may not know anything about the topic) would make a better decision about the duplicate status of the question?

I think it *should* be handled by the reopen queue. More eyes on the problem seems like as good a solution as any.

Recall also that [moderators are human exception handlers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/), and this is not really an exceptional case. A community-powered tool (the reopen queue) already exists to resolve this problem without moderator intervention, which frees up moderator time to do mod-specific tasks.

Comment: @2501 And those mistakes can be corrected...by the community.  There is no need for, nor a benefit from, moderator intervention.

Comment: @2501 Then it seems I'd rather risk several people in the reopen queue making the mistake if not reopening the question, rather than have a single moderator making the mistake of not reopening it.

Comment: -1 because you are wrongly assuming that gold badge holders will never use their damaging power on questions where the relevance of their gold tag is marginal.

Comment: @apsillers What about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193987/how-to-auto-increment-ios-notification-badge-with-firebase-cloud-messaging). It closed but it should not have closed. This is a different question. Should we wait for those gold badge users who voted it for close to reopen it? Even I'm unable to ping them in comments. So can we inform them or get their attention to this question? There should be any option or help for such things.