# Bad Marked-Duplicate Question Flag Declined

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32847726/cpp-how-to-turn-off-specific-monitor) which seemed interesting but was already marked as duplicate by a single user with a gold tag badge rather than being voted as a duplicate by consensus.  I took a look at the already-answered link and couldn't find a good answer to the question; in fact it seemed to only answer a variant of the question specifically called out as *not* what the original asker was looking for.  I couldn't find any other questions on SO that *did* answer the question, so I voted to reopen the question.

I wanted to go a bit further though because the question was (IMO erroneously) closed by a single user rather than a consensus of 5 voters, so I checked on meta and found [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254763/how-to-nominate-something-as-not-a-duplicate-when-flagged-as-a-duplicate/254765#254765) about reopening duplicates.  The accepted answer indicates *"If you believe it is not a dupe & have a strong opinion on that, just flag the question with specific details."* so that's what I did, indicating that the linked question didn't answer the original question.  Today, however, that flag was declined with the message *"flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention"*.

So what is the right path for this kind of thing?  Should I just leave my reopen vote there and hope it gets enough other votes to reopen?  My main concern with that appriach is that this kind of question is very domain-specific and not likely to get a lot of views.  For voted-diplicate questions that's fine since there were clearly enough views to get 5 close votes, so there should be enough to reopen if appropriate.  But when a question is closed by a single user, it's not guaranteed to get enough visibility to get 5 reopen votes if that person made a mistake.

Comment: Leave a comment as to *why* you've nominated it for reopening. Some of us actually read those when reviewing.

Comment: When it says "flag it to reopen" that is supposed to be for those people that can't vote to reopen yet.  Your reopen vote is sufficient.  It will end up in the review queue to reopen.  If it is worthy, people will vote to reopen.  Nothing else you need to do.

Comment: @Becuzz Do questions with 1 or more reopen votes really end up in a review queue, or is that only if they're flagged?

Comment: @MooseBoys I believe so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You flagged with a custom *other* reason with what looks in summary as a somewhat vague "I don't think this should be closed" - you neither state what action should be taken nor any justification for why it's important that a moderator should intervene in something the community (and you) can handle anyway.

The steps to be taken:

- You're a 4k user - instead of flagging, you're able to cast a re-open vote and that will bump the post into the re-open queue so that the community can either agree or disagree with you about the re-opening.
- You can leave a comment suggesting it shouldn't be closed and the reasoning why - others may see that in the re-open queue and be able to take it into account when choosing which action to take.

As to the concern it requiring 5 to counter-act a single user's dupehammer vote - that's not necessarily the case - it's possible the original closer given a reason as to why it shouldn't be closed can reverse their decision, or, another dupehammer holder will agree and reverse the decision.

So in short - while your diligence is appreciated - you don't need a moderator's intervention here, just vote to re-open and it'll go through the normal flow of things.

Comment: I should also note that it's extremely hard for a moderator to make a call on whether something is or isn't a duplicate, since we most likely don't have any expertise in the subject at hand. If we're going to overturn a community vote, we need something more specific to go on than "this is not a duplicate of the other question".

Comment: That makes sense; I wasn't aware that questions with reopen votes end up in a queue that increases their visibility.